# Can the Raspberry Pi 4B power 2.5 hard drive and SSD without a USB hub?

Tags: power, usb-power

Does Raspberry Pi 4 model B power *one* 2.5" Seagate 2TB external hard drive and a M.2 SSD connected via USB? Will official power supply suffice powering both and Pi?

Any help or insight is highly appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raspberry Pi Power Limitations](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51615/raspberry-pi-power-limitations)

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely as ALL the USB ports total 1.5a
I connected a single M.2 NVME via USB adapter and between the adapter and NVMe most of the power was consumed.

Since the 2.5" drive is SATA and you have another USB to sata adapter to power I would say no to having enough power.